# PATH is not empty after /usr/bin/env -i /bin/bash --norc --noprofile

Tags: bash, zsh, environment-variables

I cannot make sense of the results below:

```
/tmp/% /usr/bin/env -i /bin/bash --norc --noprofile
bash-5.0$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.
```

I expected `PATH` to be empty.

Actually, in a way it is:

```
bash-5.0$ /usr/bin/printenv
PWD=/tmp
SHLVL=1
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

So there's no `PATH` in the *environment*, but a non-empty `PATH` variable is still defined, and can be used by the shell to resolve commands:

```
bash-5.0$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

I realize that I can force `/usr/bin/env` to have an empty `PATH` like this:

```
/tmp/% /usr/bin/env -i PATH= /bin/bash --norc --noprofile
bash-5.0$ /usr/bin/printenv
PWD=/tmp
SHLVL=1
PATH=
_=/usr/bin/printenv
bash-5.0$ echo $PATH

bash-5.0$
```

I have two problems with this approach: 1) `PATH` is shows in the output of `/usr/bin/printenv`; I'd prefer it if it were completely gone; 2)the situation described above is not unique to `PATH`; after `/usr/bin/env -i` a lot of variables in the resulting shell session are still defined.

**Q:** What is the simplest way to start an interactive `/bin/bash` session with the least possible number of variables defined (whether in the environment or not)? <sup>1</sup>

(Though I've phrased this question in terms of `bash`, I'm also interested in any related info regarding `zsh`.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I am aware of the fact that many programs will not function normally, or function at all, if some variables are undefined.  I do not intend to use such minimal shell sessions for anything other than for troubleshooting, diagnostics, and the like.</sup>

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614420/path-is-not-empty-after-usr-bin-env-i-bin-bash-norc-noprofile, https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/19390a1ba8dc983b0a1379058e90cd51ce156815/Src/init.c#L980

Comment: `which` isn't a builtin. that may or may not affect your results, but `command -v` will at least report what the shell actually thinks

Comment: @Fox, `which` is a builtin in `zsh` (like in `tcsh`).

Comment: See also `info zsh 'Parameters Set By The Shell'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both `bash` and `zsh` (and `dash` and `mksh` and `fish` at least) set `$PATH` to a default value when not supplied in the environment they received on startup.

The POSIX shells that don't are still required to look up commands in a default search path.

Both `bash` and `zsh` (and some of the modules that are loaded automatically or not in the latter) set a number of internal variables some of which are exported to the environment (not `PATH` though in the case of `bash` and `zsh`), some of which are read-only.

`env -i zsh -f` or `env -i bash --norc` would run the shell with an empty environ.

To unset the non-readonly ones, you can do `unset ${(k)parameters}` in `zsh` or `unset -v $(compgen -v)` in `bash` (though I find that I have to run it twice for `LINES` and `COLUMNS` to disappear).

In my test, in `bash`, that still leaves:

```
<noprompt> typeset -p
declare -r BASHOPTS="checkwinsize:cmdhist:complete_fullquote:expand_aliases:extquote:force_fignore:globasciiranges:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath"
declare -a BASH_ARGC=([0]="0")
declare -a BASH_ARGV=()
declare -a BASH_LINENO=()
declare -a BASH_SOURCE=()
declare -ar BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="5" [1]="0" [2]="17" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu")
declare -ir EUID="1000"
declare -a FUNCNAME
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -a PIPESTATUS=([0]="1")
declare -ir PPID="44873"
declare -r SHELLOPTS="braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor"
declare -ir UID="1000"
declare -- _="_"
```

And in `zsh`:

```
<noprompt> printf '%s (%s)\n' ${(kv)parameters}
parameters (association-readonly-hide-hideval-special)
HISTCMD (integer-readonly-special)
! (integer-readonly-special)
# (integer-readonly-special)
$ (integer-readonly-special)
* (array-readonly-special)
- (scalar-readonly-special)
0 (scalar-special)
ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT (scalar-readonly-tied-special)
ZSH_SUBSHELL (integer-readonly-special)
? (integer-readonly-special)
@ (array-readonly-special)
zsh_eval_context (array-readonly-tied-special)
status (integer-readonly-special)
TTYIDLE (integer-readonly-special)
LINENO (integer-readonly-special)
PPID (integer-readonly-special)
ARGC (integer-readonly-special)
```

Answer (score 2):

Any shell will use a "default" path (usually including at least `/bin` and `/usr/bin`) to lookup commands if the `PATH` envvar isn't defined. That behaviour is also replicated by `execvp(2)`.

Some shells (like [bash](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c?id=ac50fbac377e32b98d2de396f016ea81e8ee9961#n447)) will even set the `PATH` shell variable to their default path in that case.

> What is the simplest way to start an interactive `/bin/bash` session with the least possible number of variables defined (whether in the environment or not)?

```
env - bash --norc
```

> `bash-5.0$ which ls`

`which` is not a bash built-in -- on some systems it's a shell script run by a *different* shell than bash. So it's completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Note that `which` is a builtin in `zsh` (like in `tcsh`). See also [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249). Note that GNU's and some BSD's `which` are not implemented as shell scripts.

Comment: thanks, corrected